# Ant target to move directories out of another directory

Tags: file, ant

What is the simplest way to move everything out of a target directory?

I have this `basedir/parentdir/<subdir>`. I have many different `<subdir>`. I need to move them out into the same level as `parentdir` so that it becomes `basedir/<subdir>`. Now, each `<subdir>` contains a deep tree of many other subdirectories and files, including empty subdirectories.

I've tried the following:

```
<move todir="basedir">
    <fileset dir="parentdir">
        <include name="**/*.*" />
    </fileset>
</move>
```

That failed to move the empty directories - meaning after the move, all the `<subdir>` are missing their empty subdirectories. "move" supposedly copies emptysubdirectories by default, so I tried the following next:

```
<move todir="basedir">
    <fileset dir="parentdir">
        <include name="**/*" />
        <include name="**/*.*" />
    </fileset>
</move>
```

While I did manage to move the empty subdirectories, the strange thing is that all the immediate subdirectories of all the `<subdir>` gets copied into `basedir`. Every `<subdir>` has `src`, `test`, and `build`. These are now sitting in `basedir` as well as in their original moved `<subdir>`.

I'm positive I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. Am I approaching things the wrong way?

Comment: You don't use flatten=true, do you?

Comment: you problably need to move them to a temporary location first...

Comment: @John: Nope, I want to retain the dir structure.
@mike: Actually, "parentdir" _is_ a temporary location for me :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
<project name="moveproject" basedir="." default="moveDirs">
<target name="moveDirs">
    <move todir="${basedir}" includeEmptyDirs="yes" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="parentdir" >
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </move>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: includeEmptyDirs is supposed to be true by default so I didn't set it. Also, the example in Ant doc used includeemptydirs="false" instead of yes/no... strange. **/* was correct. I scrapped my old targets and rewrote most of it. I think my original target that set up the parentdir had problems. Copied yours in and things are working as intended. Thanks!

Comment: What if I don't know the name of parentdir?